# select only values with specific keys

Tags: jquery

I have a table into which I want to generate a row for each data obj containing the values for some specific keys. `data` returns an array containing objects. I manually set the `<th>` (`tableTh` const), which is also the names of some of the keys. I don't know how to return only the values which have the keys that are equal to the `tableTh` const...

I have tried to use the `filter` function but it doesn't work.

```
this.tableDevicesbyAlarmsTime = function (data) {

        const table = $('#topAlarmsDeviceLine');
        var i = 1;
        var headerRow = $('<tr>');
        const tableTh = ['device', 'processor', 'ram', 'swap', 'services'];
        Object.keys(data).map(function (key) {
            console.log(data);
            var alarmsTime = data[key].number / 60;
        });

        tableTh.forEach(value => {
            const th = $("<th>").text(value);
            headerRow.append(th);
        });
        table.append($('<thead>').append(headerRow));
console.log(data.filter(tableTh));
        data.forEach(obj => {
            const row = $('<tr>');
            Object.values(obj).forEach(value => {
                //here**
                const cell = row.append($('<td>').text(value));
                row.append(cell);
            });
            table.append(row);
        });

    };
```

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: You use `Object.keys(data)` as if `data` is an object; then you use `data.filter` as if it is an array.

Comment: is an array which contains objects...Array[0: Object { device_id: "95", Denumire: "OG", processor: "30", … }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not made it clear whether each object in `data` has all of the keys defined in `tableTh`, but I will assume that it does.

To get the HTML for the table rows, you must have a loop mapping each object to a row and an inner loop which maps each `tableTh` key to a table cell value  from the object in the outer loop.

```js
function populate(data) {
  const table = $('#topAlarmsDeviceLine');
  var headerRow = $('<tr>');
  const tableTh = ['device', 'processor', 'ram', 'swap', 'services'];

  tableTh.forEach(value => {
    const th = $("<th>").text(value);
    headerRow.append(th);
  });
  table.append($('<thead>').append(headerRow));
  
  const mapObjValueToTableCell = value => {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
      return '<td></td>';
    }
    return `<td>${value}</td>`;
  };

  const html = data.map(obj => {
    return `
      <tr>
        ${tableTh.map(key => mapObjValueToTableCell(obj[key])).join('')}
      </tr>
    `;
  }).join('');
  
  table.append('<tbody>').append(html);
};

populate([
  {
    device_id: "95",
    Denumire: "OG",
    processor: "30"
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="topAlarmsDeviceLine"></table>
```